Fit Measures inside existing table
First table in matrix I.E.

Measures

I've tried using IF with Selected Value I've tried to Mapping but
in result my measures are coming up as blank.
However If I use Measure(Gross Profit) alone in singled out matrix it breaks down the value into each category Revenue and Cost of Goods Sold rather than giving me total sum
I've tried using IF with Selected value to MAP the measure and link it to Category Separate table which I created to use in Rows of Matrix
Here is the sample end result I want showing Main Table with Measures incorporated


maybe you need to create several measures for different category
e.g.
Revenue = calculate(sum(value), category ="Revenue"))

Then  create a dim table for Measures
At last use the selectedvalue function
=if ( selectedvalue(measure)="Revenue", [Revenue])

